# Emogrifier removes all content on page

Tags: php, html, css

I'm trying make Emogrifier work with my page, but as I'm new to Emogrifier I'm having a hard time making it work properly. I followed the github documentation, but was unsure as of how to execute and use it, so I simply inserted the given code into my .php file:

```
<?php 
$html = '<button id="updatecv" name="updatecv" class="cvupdater">Opdater CV</button>';
$css = 'cvupdater {margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;margin-bottom:20px;display:block;width:150px;}';
$emogrifier = new \Pelago\Emogrifier($html, $css);

?>

<?php
try {
    require "config.php";
    require "common.php";
    $id = $_GET['cvid'];
    $connection = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password, $options);
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM cvs WHERE id = :cvid";
    $statement = $connection->prepare($sql);
    $statement->bindParam(':cvid', $id, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $statement->execute();
    $result = $statement->fetchAll();
}
catch(PDOException $error) {
    echo $sql . "<br>" . $error->getMessage();
}
?>

<?php include "header.php"; ?>

<p class="hidden" id="hiddencvid"><?php echo $id ?></p>



<button id="updatecv" name="updatecv" class="cvupdater">Opdater CV</button>
<p class="cvupdater" style="width:500px;">Tryk på tekst for at redigere. Tryk på "Opdater CV" for at gemme ændringer.</p>

<a href="index.php">Hjem</a>

<div class="cvpreview">

<?php foreach($result as $row) { ?>


<div class="cvheader">
  <div id="img-wrapper">
    <img src="uploads/<?php echo escape($row["cvid"]) . ".png" ?>" alt="profile_picture">
  </div>
  <h1><?php echo escape($row["fullname"])?></h1>
  <div contenteditable class="cvheader-worktitle" id="worktitle"><?php $decodedworktitle = html_entity_decode($row["worktitle"]); echo $decodedworktitle?></div>
</div>

<hr>

<div class="cvbody">
    <div class="leftcolumn">
      <div class="profil columnboxleft">
        <h5>Profil</h5>
        <div contenteditable class="cvtext" id="profiledesc"><?php $decodedprofiledesc = html_entity_decode($row["profiledesc"]); echo $decodedprofiledesc?></div>
      </div>   
      <div class="workexperience columnboxleft">
        <h5>Arbejdserfaring</h5>  
        <div contenteditable class="cvtext" id="workexperience"><?php $decodedworkexperience = html_entity_decode($row["workexperience"]); echo $decodedworkexperience?></div>  
      </div>
      <div class="education columnboxleft">
        <h5>Uddannelse</h5>
        <div contenteditable class="cvtext" id="education"><?php $decodededucation = html_entity_decode($row["education"]); echo $decodededucation?></div>  
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="rightcolumn">
      <div class="details columnboxright">
        <h5>Detaljer</h5>
        <div contenteditable class="cvtext" id="phonenumber"><?php $decodedphonenumber = html_entity_decode($row["phonenumber"]); echo $decodedphonenumber?></div>
        <div contenteditable class="cvtext" id="email"><?php $decodedemail = html_entity_decode($row["email"]); echo $decodedemail?></div>
        <div contenteditable class="cvtext" id="birthdate"><?php $decodedbirthdate = html_entity_decode($row["birthdate"]); echo $decodedbirthdate?></div>
      </div>
      <div class="skills columnboxright">
        <h5>Evner</h5>
        <div contenteditable class="cvtext" id="skills"><?php $decodedskills = html_entity_decode($row["skills"]); echo $decodedskills?></div>
      </div>
      <div class="languages columnboxright">
        <h5>Sprog</h5>
        <div contenteditable class="cvtext" id="languages"><?php $decodedlanguages = html_entity_decode($row["languages"]); echo $decodedlanguages?></div>
      </div>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
</div>

</div>
<?php include "footer.php"; ?>
```

However, where ever I insert the emogrifier code, the content following that snippet gets completely removed from my page.

Placing the snippet at the bottom of the file does make the page render, but the function of emogrifier doesn't seem to apply.

Comment: Hm, not sure, but `$css = 'cvupdater` ... you're missing a `.`: `$css = '.cvupdater`.

Comment: @kerbholz ah yea, fixed that - thanks. Same issue though.